# How can I disable custom editor in SnippetDesigner and keep other features?

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, code-snippets, visual-studio-extensions

I use the **[SnippetDesigner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-2795.SnippetDesigner)** extension for Visual Studio mainly for its **Export to Snippet** feature. But, once exported, I prefer to edit my snippets in VS as XML rather than using the custom editor that is also part of SnippetDesigner.

Is there an easy way to turn the snippet editor off while keeping the export feature? Either Visual Studio settings or configuration of the extension itself will meet my needs.

I'm using the extension in Visual Studio 2017, community edition.  I prefer a solution that is not tied to a specific version or edition.

Comment: It seems no option for this SnippetDesigner to control its behavior. You may add your suggestion to developers on [github](https://github.com/mmanela/SnippetDesigner) but as I check, this extension haven't updated for a long time. So maybe your answer is the best workaround for now. You can mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far, I was able to get most of what I want by going to **Tools > Options > Text Editor > File Extension** and adding **XML (Text) Editor** for the `.snippet` extension.

[image]

However, one shortcoming of this seems to be that when I access the file via **File > Recent Files** and the file was accessed using the custom editor at the time it was added to the MRU file list, I still do get the custom editor which I don't want to use.  It's a minor point, but there still may be a better resolution.